# Tokenizing Preprocessed text with Scikit-learn

Tags: python, hadoop, scikit-learn, bigdata

I recently created a hadoop job that takes thousands of text files and performs some basic text processing. When the job is done, I have two output files that I am using to train for positive and negative sentiments. Both files look like this:

**word1 num_occurrences**
**...**
**wordN num_occurrences**

I want to use sci-kit learn to classify using support vector machines, but I am not sure how because I am not sure how to tokenize my dataset correctly. All of the tutorials assume that you are feeding raw text files to `sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer` and haven't done any preprocessing. I've tried using the `FeatureHasher` as well, but rather than hashing a single word and creating a sparse matrix, it is creating a hash for every single character that I pass it.

That said, does anyone have any ideas for the best way to extract features and pass them to a machine learning algorithm given my current output files? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [TfidfTransformer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer.html).

Since you are using text features, [TF-IDF representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) will assign each feature (word) a number representing its importance in the text. This representation is very common in text-based classification.

The TfidfTransformer will output a matrix with all the words used in your files, each row representing a document and each cell in the row represents a feature (word) and the value in the cell is the importance of that feature.

Make sure that you pass it your word count data in the appropriate format (matrix) and then with the output of this TfidfTtransformer you can train your classifier.

(I haven't used it so far, only the Vectorizer version, but I have seen scenarios where it does what you want).

Comment: The part I don't quite understand is how to transform what I have into an input to the TfidfTransformer. I tried creating an array  like this: `[ [word1, count], [word2, count] ...]`  and then passing it to the fit function, but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you get started.

```
import numpy as np
import copy
from numpy import *
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn import preprocessing

x_temp_list = []
y_temp_list = []
y_train_text = []
temp_list = []
another_temp_list = []

with open('newtrain.csv','r') as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines()

for line in lines:
    if len(line.strip()) > 1:
        fields = line.split(',')
        if len(line.split(',')) == 2:
            x_temp_list.append(fields[0].strip())
            y_temp_list.append(fields[1].strip())

X_train = np.array(x_temp_list)
y_train_text = np.array(y_temp_list)

X_test = np.array(['Barista'])

mlb = preprocessing.LabelBinarizer()
Y = mlb.fit_transform(y_train_text)

classifier = Pipeline([
    ('vectorizer', CountVectorizer()),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
    ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC()))])

classifier.fit(X_train, Y)
predicted = classifier.predict(X_test)
all_labels = mlb.inverse_transform(predicted)
#all_labels = lb.inverse_transform(predicted)

for item, labels in zip(X_test, all_labels):
    print '%s => %s' % (item, labels)
```